# How to know if a data contains non-ascii character?

Tags: python, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I'm working with an api which returns some data in the form of `01234⇒56789`. Sometimes this data has only numbers which is not a problem but sometimes it returns `⇒` character. As I have to automate the filtering process of selecting the number after the arrow (non-ascii character) I have to know when the characters contains a non-ascii character.

I used `decode(utf-8)` and it returns `u'01234\u21d256789'` . I tried `split('\u21d2')` but the string is not splitting. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python3:

```
>>> s = "01234⇒56789"
>>> s
'01234⇒56789'
>>> s.split("⇒")
['01234', '56789']
```

python2:

```
>>> s = u"01234⇒56789"
>>> s.split(u"⇒")
[u'01234', u'56789']
```

the key point in Python2 is to specify that you deal with an unicode string. In Python3 strings are unicode by default and there's [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings) type

Comment: Nice and concise answer. Only one minor point: if you don't specify the encoding at the top of your program, `s=u'01234⇒56789'` will give an 'Unsupported characters in input' error. Therefore, I would use `s.split(u'\u21d2')`instead.

Comment: Well, I'm using UTF-8 encoding in console by default, so it's not a problem for me and works as specified. But surely one might need the specify input encoding or use backslash-u coding explicitly.